# facebook integration issue IOS

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm trying to integrate facebook in my iOS 5 application.
As mentioned in facebook documentation, i'm doing everything as they mentioned.
Usually when facebook is initiated to authorize, it will take the user to browser opening facebook website and asks to authenticate. but in my case, it opens browser and immediately it goes back to the app. I didn't understand what's happening.

And it posted nothing on facebook. It just had a transition to the native app and then come back again.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 

{



    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"SELECT uid, name, pic, email FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",nil];

    [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];

    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Facebook"
                              message:@"You are successfully signed in."
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil,
                              nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:2];
    [alertView show];

    NSLog(@"signed in");
       }


if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"publish_stream",

                            nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];


}
```

else if ([facebook isSessionValid]) {
       facebookOut.hidden=NO;

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add permissions to be authorized by the user??? something similar to this

```
   NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"user_likes", 
        @"read_stream",
        nil];
   [facebook authorize:permissions];
   [permissions release];
```